# Select Algorithm Implementation

Tags: algorithm

I have implemented "Select" algorithm which is described in "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen. This algorithm returns the ith smallest element in an array. My code is working fine for quite large input say "36000" but if I run the same code for large numbers say 1000000 I get stackoverflow error. However according to me the number is not so big so that recursion causes stackoverflow. Any light on this will be of great help

Here is the link to my code.

"https://github.com/ChandanBP/MyProjects/blob/master/Select%20Algorithm".

Here is the exception I am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:42)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
    at Chap3.Selection.divide(Selection.java:53)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Increase stack size significantly. Did it help? The stack size was the problem. Didn't it? Not sure, but most likely you have an endless loop bug\

Comment: @amit: Endless loop bugs don't cause stack overflows.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing the right selection algorithm? The first thing it seems to do is sort the entire array, and then it goes on doing more stuff. This is not how selection is supposed to work.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError "Endless loop" as endless recursive calls.

Comment: @n.m. Select algorithm does not sort the input array entirely. It just sorts the elements around the value we want. Also I am getting ith smallest element for small values, exception is occurring only for large values of n.

Comment: @amit I increased stack size in eclipse run configurations. But still no luck.Also if it is endless loop then it has to fail for even smaller values of n.

Comment: Ah ok. It only sorts the array partially. Still not clear why you need anything between the start of select and the first call to partition.

Comment: @n.m. If you look at the algorithm steps it says first we have to divide the input array into n/5 groups of 5 elements each. Find the medians of those n/5 groups. Then find median of medians. So that is what being implemented there.

Comment: Well that's one convoluted way of doing medians of 5. I don't think you are doing it entirely right, but that's not the issue. Your divide function consumes O(n) of stack. This is not right however you look at it. If you absolutely must do it recursively, divide the array into two approximately equal parts and call `divide` on each part.